# ZF2 - How to troubleshoot Zend Framework 2 database connection issues

Tags: zend-framework2

I have started learning ZF2 and have been trying to get a basic CRUD working. To learn how to do this I have followed a number of tutorials:

1. From the book, ZF2, learning by example
2. https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/release-2.0.0/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Currently I can not get any of the tutorials to work having copied them word for word. I keep hitting 404 pages. This to me suggests a routing problem somewhere however as I am new to this, I am certain there are quite a few variables to consider.

So my questions:

1. Where can I find a simple, working CRUD module that connects to a simple database and will work from word go? This will help to eliminate the module being the issue and I will then be able to look at other potential issues.
2. What is best practice when troubleshooting with ZF2? For instance, if I am getting a 404 page, how do I know what page was requested?

[Edit] - Adding further comments and some code:

In the example below, the register process works without a hitch so long as I do not attempt to add the information to the database. So if I comment out:

```
// Create user
    //$this->createUser($form->getData());
```

I am diverted to the register complete page. which means the issue has something to do with:

```
    protected function createUser(array $data)
{
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User);
    $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user',
    $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
    $user = new User();
    $user->exchangeArray($data);
    $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);
    $userTable->saveUser($user);
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot the above?

view/users/register/index.phtml

```
<section class="register">
<h2>Register</h2>
<?php if ($this->error): ?>
    <p class="error">
        There were one or more issues with your submission.
        Please correct them as
        indicated below.
    </p>
<?php endif ?>

<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(NULL,
    array('controller'=>'register', 'action' => 'process')));
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>

<dl class="zend_form">
    <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('name')); ?></dt>
    <dd><?php
        echo $this->formElement($form->get('name'));
        echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('name'));
        ?></dd>
    <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('email')); ?></dt>
    <dd><?php
        echo $this->formElement($form->get('email'));
        echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('email'));
        ?></dd>
    <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('password'));
        ?></dt>
    <dd><?php
        echo $this->formElement($form->get('password'));
        echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('password'));
        ?></dd>
    <dt><?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('confirm_password')); ?></dt>
    <dd><?php
        echo $this->formElement($form->get('confirm_password'));
        echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('confirm_password'));
        ?></dd>
    <dd><?php
        echo $this->formElement($form->get('submit'));
        echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('submit'));
        ?></dd>
</dl>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
```

src/Users/Form/RegisterForm.php

```
<?php
// filename : module/Users/src/Users/Form/RegisterForm.php

namespace Users\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class RegisterForm extends Form
{
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    parent::__construct('Register');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('enctype','multipart/form-data');

    //Add the required fields using the add method
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'attributes' => array('type' => 'text',),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Full Name',
        ),
    ));

    //Additional validators and filters
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'options' => array('label' => 'Email',),
        'attributes' => array('required' => 'required','type' => 'email'),
        'filters' => array( array( 'name' => 'StringTrim' ), ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                'options' => array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'Email address     format is invalid'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ));

    //Add a password field
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'password',
        'attributes' => array('type' => 'password',),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Password',
        ),
    ));

    //Add a confirm password field
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'confirm_password',
        'attributes' => array('type' => 'password',),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Confirm password',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array('type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Add'),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Register',
        ),
    ));


}
}
```

src/USers/Controller/RegisterController.php

```
<?php
namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Users\Form\RegisterForm;
use Users\Form\RegisterFilter;

class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{

public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new RegisterForm();
    $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
    return $viewModel;
}

public function confirmAction()
{
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    return $viewModel;
}

public function processAction()
{
    if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL ,
            array( 'controller' => 'register',
                'action' => 'index'
            ));
    }
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
    $form = new RegisterForm();
    $inputFilter = new RegisterFilter();
    $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
    $form->setData($post);
    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        $model = new ViewModel(array(
            'error' => true,
            'form'  => $form,
        ));

        $model->setTemplate('users/register/index');
        return $model;
    }

    // Create user
    $this->createUser($form->getData());

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array(
        'controller' => 'register',
        'action' =>  'confirm'
    ));
}

protected function createUser(array $data)
{
    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Users\Model\User);
    $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user',
    $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
    $user = new User();
    $user->exchangeArray($data);
    $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);
    $userTable->saveUser($user);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Assuming you started with the ZF skeleton app, are you getting a Zend Framework styled 404 page? If yes, it's likely to be a routing issue. If no, and it's a plain old Apache 404 page, check that you've enabled mod_rewrite, and that your .htaccess file is being used.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your input. I have updated my question to include some code. The app crashes only when I try to add data to the database, if I comment out that section, it goes through the motions of validation and diverts to the correct page.

Comment: And yes - I do get a 404 error page as per the application/view/404.phtml page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after googling about I have found the problem. Essentially the database details are not being included automatically. To include them and resolve this issue I added the following to application.conofig.php and to the module_listener_options:

```
    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

As to the best way for troubleshooting ZF2 apps (that I've found) is to use XDebug (or similar) and be able to step through the execution.

Along with that, the [Zend Developer Tools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) module may be very helpful during development.

If you turn on `display_exceptions` in the `view_manager` configuration, you should be able to see what's actually causing the issue.

Comment: Ahh, okay the error page being called was not outputting the actual error message. I updated this and now the error I see is this: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter